# Best way to center a custom shape inside of a parent view?

Tags: swiftui, shapes

[image]

I think the picture says it all. The view itself is centered, but since the shape does not fill the entire frame, the shape isn't centered. My question is simply what is the best approach to fix this.

- One way would be to instead of starting from `minX` to go from `midX` and the same thing with `minY` but doing this I would have to compute the *overshoot* or offset to counter that..
- The other way (well the way I'm hoping for) is to somehow adjust it with a parent view and a `GeometryReader`

Here is the relevant code, (its just a simple square)

```
    struct FilterShape: Shape {
    //Modeled from 60inches being maximum or 100%
    let width: CGFloat
    let height: CGFloat
    var widthPercentage: CGFloat {
        width / 60
    }
    var heightPercentage: CGFloat {
        height / 60
    }
    let isSquare: Bool
    func path(in rect: CGRect) -> Path {
        var path = Path()
        if !isSquare {
        path.move(to: CGPoint(x: rect.minX, y: rect.minY))
        path.addLine(to: CGPoint(x: rect.maxX * widthPercentage, y: rect.minY))
        path.addLine(to: CGPoint(x: rect.maxX * widthPercentage, y: rect.maxX * heightPercentage))
        path.addLine(to: CGPoint(x: rect.minX, y: rect.maxX * heightPercentage))
        path.closeSubpath()
        } else {
            path.move(to: CGPoint(x: rect.minX, y: rect.minY))
            path.addLine(to: CGPoint(x: rect.maxX * widthPercentage, y: rect.minY))
            path.addLine(to: CGPoint(x: rect.maxX * widthPercentage, y: rect.maxX * widthPercentage))
            path.addLine(to: CGPoint(x: rect.minX, y: rect.maxX * widthPercentage))
            path.closeSubpath()
        }
        return path
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This is my current workaround.

`return path.offsetBy(dx: rect.width * 0.17, dy: rect.height * 0.17)`

Offsetting the final path (by a number I experimented with to get) gave me this result:

[image]

which will work but will overshoot the parents frame under certain conditions